# Is there a way I can retrieve the values from the tuples?

Tags: r

Please I have this cyber attack dataset that I need to analyse and I need to extract the values to form columns. For example, [PSH ACK] Seq=337 Ack=641 Win=2903 Len=112 Tsval=2297897 ...etc, and when extracted it will be: 337 under Seq, 641 under Ack, 2903 under Win....etc. The output should look like this

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg9oA.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! can you please provide a reproducible example instead of a screenshot, and an example of a desired outcome? your question is not easy to understand as it is. Keep in mind that the easier you make it for others to understand your question, the easier it will be to provide guidance / advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the code fits your real case, but you can have a try on it:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(`class<-`(do.call(rbind,regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\d+",s))),"numeric")),
               c("Seq","Ack","Win","Len","Tsval"))
```

such that

```
> df
  Seq Ack  Win Len   Tsval
1 337 641 2903 112 2297897
2   1  16  436 160 2297898
```

**Dummy Data**

```
s <- c("[PSH ACK] Seq=337 Ack=641 Win=2903 Len=112 Tsval=2297897",
       "[PSH ACK] Seq=1 Ack=16 Win=436 Len=160 Tsval=2297898")
```

Comment: df <- setNames(data.frame(`class<-`(do.call(rbind,regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\d+",Prot_Inf$Info))),"numeric")),
+                c("Seq","Ack","Win","Len","Tsval"))
Error in regmatches(s, gregexpr("\\d+", Prot_Inf$Info)) : 
  object 's' not found

Answer (score 1):

An option using `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
fields <- c("Seq", "Ack", "Win", "Len")
sapply(
  fields, 
  function(f) as.integer(stri_extract(s, regex = sprintf("(?<=%s=)[0-9]+", f)))
)
     Seq Ack  Win Len
[1,] 337 641 2903 112
[2,]   1  16  436 160
```

Burrowing Thomas' dummy data:

```
s <- c("[PSH ACK] Seq=337 Ack=641 Win=2903 Len=112 Tsval=2297897",
       "[PSH ACK] Seq=1 Ack=16 Win=436 Len=160 Tsval=2297898")
```